# How do i achieve having slick with center mode to work with fade true not working for me

Tags: jquery

```
$('.story-slider').slick({
  // fade:true,
  centerMode:true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  adaptiveHeight:false,
  arrows:true,
  prevArrow: $('.prev'),
  nextArrow: $('.next'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `fade` with `centerMode` as fade is for fading a single item, but `centerMode` centers when we have multiple items.

You can set `slidesToShow` to one item.